# Open multi files with batch file

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch-file, irfanview

I have a trouble when I open multi images with Irfanview . It only opens one file, and after I close the window, it opens next one. I want to open three windows instantly.

I hope someone help me out.

Here is my batch files:

```
 "e:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "C:\Users\Workgroup23\Documents\Visual Studio 

2008\Projects\OpenCL\OpenCL\outputCPU.pgm" 

 "e:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "C:\Users\Workgroup23\Documents\Visual Studio 

2008\Projects\OpenCL\OpenCL\outputGPU.pgm"

 "e:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "C:\Users\Workgroup23\Documents\Visual Studio 

2008\Projects\OpenCL\OpenCL\lena.pgm"
```

PS: Merry Christmas :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `start` command, i.e.:

```
@echo off
start "c:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" IMG_0707.JPG
start "c:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" IMG_0709.JPG
```

Comment: Ah, I got your idea. But it's already unchecked :(

Comment: @Tiana987642 and this one?